# Changing the date format for a date range programmatically

Tags: java, android, date-formatting, date-range, android-date

I have an application where I want to change the date format in 'From' and 'To'.

Lets assume, I have a date range like `2018-06-11 - 2018-06-14`. Now, I want to change it in some other format as `11 June, 2018 - 14 June, 2018`.

Please refer the code below, I have tried:

```
        String strDate = "2018-06-11 - 2018-06-14";
        SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        try {
            Date date = format.parse(strDate);
            format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMMM, yyyy");
            String strFinalDate = format.format(date);
            tv4.setText(strFinalDate);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Also, I tried the below code as well:

```
        String strDate = "2018-06-11 - 2018-06-14";
        SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd - yyyy-MM-dd");
        try {
            Date date = format.parse(strDate);
            format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMMM, yyyy - dd MMMM, yyyy");
            String strFinalDate = format.format(date);
            tv4.setText(strFinalDate);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

First, set of code runs smoothly, but converts only the 'From' and doesn't even checks for 'To' date.
And, second set of code returns an error which says, `java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "2017-01-11 - 2017-01-14`

Have I skipped anything in this code?

Please notify me if I have.

Thanks!

Comment: these packages are deprecated try date and time

Comment: @Lokesh I have to use this..

Comment: I will say take date from `String strDate = "2018-06-11 - 2018-06-14";` and split the dates using `-` and then change the format and then append it using `-`

Comment: Split `String strDate = "2018-06-11 - 2018-06-14";` into two different `String` variables e.g. `String fromDate = "2018-06-11";` and `String toDate = 2018-06-14";` Then try to parse and format these two strings.

Comment: Thanks mate! it worked!!

Comment: Consider throwing away the long outmoded and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` and friends, and adding [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) to your Android project in order to use `java.time`, the modern Java date and time API. It is so much nicer to work with.

Comment: just looking at the example code, what actually did you expect to have into the date object: `Date date = format.parse("2018-06-11 - 2018-06-14");` ??

Answer (score 2):

I suggest

```
    DateTimeFormatter dateFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDate(FormatStyle.LONG);
    String strDate = "2018-06-11 - 2018-06-14";
    String[] strDates = strDate.split(" - ");
    if (strDates.length != 2) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Wrong range format " + strDate 
                + ", must be yyyy-MM-dd - yyyy-MM-dd");
    }
    String strFinalDate = LocalDate.parse(strDates[0]).format(dateFormatter)
            + " - " + LocalDate.parse(strDates[1]).format(dateFormatter);
    System.out.println(strFinalDate);
```

Output on my Java with US English locale:

> 11 June 2018 - 14 June 2018

You don’t get the comma after “June” because this is not considered standard, so consider if this isn’t really an advantage. The output will depend on locale setting, which may be an advantage too. Or specify explicit locale for example:

```
    DateTimeFormatter dateFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDate(FormatStyle.LONG)
            .withLocale(Locale.UK);
```

I am using and recommending `java.time`, the modern Java date and time API.

### What went wrong in your code?

No matter if you use an old-fashiuoned `Date` or a modern `LocalDate`, such an object can only hold one date, not a date range. In your first attempt `SimpleDateFormat` parsed the first date (since it matched your pattern) and then ignored the remainder of the string. So when you formatted the parsed date, you got

> 11 June, 2018

In your seconds attempt both dates were parsed, but into the same `Date` object, so only the values of the second date were kept. When printing the date its values were also printed twice since the format pattern for formatting contains the format twice:

> 14 June, 2018 - 14 June, 2018

### Question: Can I use java.time on Android?

Yes, `java.time` works nicely on older and newer Android devices. It just requires at least Java **6**.

- In Java 8 and later and on newer Android devices (from API level 26, I’m told) the modern API comes built-in.
- In Java 6 and 7 get the ThreeTen Backport, the backport of the new classes (ThreeTen for JSR 310; see the links at the bottom).
- On (older) Android use the Android edition of ThreeTen Backport. It’s called ThreeTenABP. And make sure you import the date and time classes from `org.threeten.bp` with subpackages.

### Links

- [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use `java.time`.
- [Java Specification Request (JSR) 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310), where `java.time` was first described.
- [ThreeTen Backport project](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/), the backport of `java.time`to Java 6 and 7 (ThreeTen for JSR-310).
- [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP), Android edition of ThreeTen Backport
- [Question: How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project), with a very thorough explanation.

Comment: thank you for not encouraging OP to use deprecated packages. This answer should be accepted.

Answer (score 0):

As I stated in my comment above, you have to split your `strDate` `String` into two different `String` variables. Have a look at the code below

```
    String strDate = "2018-06-11 - 2018-06-14";
    String[] fromToDatesStr = strDate.split(" - ");
    String fromDateStr = fromToDatesStr[0];
    String toDateStr = fromToDatesStr[1];
    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    Date fromDate = null;
    Date toDate = null;
    try {
        fromDate = format.parse(fromDateStr);
        toDate = format.parse(toDateStr);
        format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMMM, yyyy");
        String strFromFinalDate = format.format(fromDate);
        String strToFinalDate = format.format(toDate);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

`String strFromFinalDate` and `String strToFinalDate` now contain the dates formatted as you desire.

Comment: That's what I wrote in my comment before you. But why don't you let OP try ?

Comment: @Lokesh That's what I also wrote into my comment (posted almost the same time as yours). However, I don't see any reason why not to answer the OP question.

Comment: You have all the rights to answer but I believe the difference in giving logic and giving solution

Comment: If the given logic solution didn't worked then you would have given your code

Comment: If I were a teacher and the OP was my student I would agree with you. If my answer is against SO rules please flag it and moderators will take care of it. Thanks

Comment: I am not against your answer. I am just saying let the OP try. Because you have already written this in your comment and then few minutes later an answer. I don't see any point of that comment.